# can I use EmbeddedRecordsMixin with RESTSerializer?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember with mongodb backend. There's a need to illustrate my embedded objects for Ember Data model. EmbeddedRecordsMixin looks like what I need, but its under activemodel-adapter package and documentation example uses ActiveModelSerializer? So is it only for activemodel or can I use it with regular RESTSerializer?

Comment: Did you try at all? Have you read the source code? It seems like it could work, since only `extractArray` and `extractSingle` call `_super`, and those two methods are not adapted/implemented by the ActiveModelSerializer.